# from a C# method, how to call and run a DLL, where the DLL name comes from a String variable?

Tags: c#, .net, interop, pinvoke

I am new to C#.NET. I am writing a method where I need to call and run a DLL file, where the DLL file name comes from a String variable-

```
String[] spl;

String DLLfile = spl[0];
```

How do I import this DLL and call a function from the DLL to get the return value? I tried the the following way..

```
String DLLfile = "MyDLL.dll";

[DllImport(DLLfile, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
```

But it did not worked, as The string should be in 'const string' type and 'const string' does not support variables. Please help me with detail procedure. Thanks.

Comment: There any reason the name of the dll must be contained in a string?  This seems dangerous with very few legit reasons for doing this.

Comment: Is the dll another .NET assembly? or perhaps a c++ dll?  or even a COM dll?.

Comment: @Ramhound The reason for doing it is so you can specify full path to DLL. Otherwise you are dependent on library search order. Which is dangerous. Specifying full path is the approach that avoids danger!

Comment: Firstly, please edit your question instead of posting code in comments.

Comment: Then launch Visual Studio Command Prompt and use [DUMPBIN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) to get the list of functions exported by the DLL. E.g. `DUMPBIN /exports ABC.dll`. You can also use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) for this.

Answer (score 5):

For native DLLs you can create the following static class:

```
internal static class NativeWinAPI
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule,
        string procedureName);
}
```

And then use it as follows:

```
// DLLFileName is, say, "MyLibrary.dll"
IntPtr hLibrary = NativeWinAPI.LoadLibrary(DLLFileName);

if (hLibrary != IntPtr.Zero) // DLL is loaded successfully
{
    // FunctionName is, say, "MyFunctionName"
    IntPtr pointerToFunction = NativeWinAPI.GetProcAddress(hLibrary, FunctionName);

    if (pointerToFunction != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        MyFunctionDelegate function = (MyFunctionDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
            pointerToFunction, typeof(MyFunctionDelegate));
        function(123);
    }

    NativeWinAPI.FreeLibrary(hLibrary);
}
```

Where `MyFunctionDelegate` is a [`delegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). E.g.:

```
delegate void MyFunctionDelegate(int i);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `LoadAssembly` method , and `CreateInstance` method in order to invoke method

```
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load("example");
        // Get the type to use.
        Type myType = a.GetType("Example");
        // Get the method to call.
        MethodInfo myMethod = myType.GetMethod("MethodA");
        // Create an instance. 
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
        // Execute the method.
        myMethod.Invoke(obj, null);
```

Comment: The question makes it clear that the context is unmanaged DLLs

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I wouldn't say that it is so clear. It wasn't mentioned anywhere. Nowhere in his question the OP said that he was trying to load a managed or unmanaged assembly. He talked about *a DLL*. I've already seen questions here from people who didn't know how to reference a managed assembly in another managed assembly and were trying to use the DllImport attribute. They probably didn't even know the difference between managed and unmanaged code.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I took `DllImport` to imply native DLL.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes, I am just saying that I made this mistake also once :-) It's too bad that the OP is not participating in this discussion, as if he didn't care much about his question.

Comment: Hi, I tried all the way you specified... but not able to load the assembly... Yes I don't have much idea about managed and unmanaged assembly. I am getting DLL file name, Namespace name, Class Name and Method Name dynamically and the return type is always Double in Type. If you can specify in detail how to run the DLL dynamically, it will be a great help to me.